# How to remove check constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, create-table, check-constraints

I am having difficult to remove CHECK using Alter in sql. Can anyone help me please?

```
CREATE TABLE MyProject_COST (
    ID int(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    detail varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
    cost int(6) CONSTRAINT cost_project CHECK(cost>=500)
);

ALTER TABLE MyProject_COST ALTER COLUMN Cost int(6)
```

Comment: What specific database? For SQL Server, it would be `ALTER TABLE .. DROP CONSTRAINT ..` dunno about others.

Comment: @user2864740 Oracle server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does have an `alter table ... drop constraint` syntax for this.

But since you created an anonymous constraint, so this is tricky - because you don't know the name of the constraint.

One option is to use dynamic SQL to retrieve the constraint name, and drop it with an `execute immediate` command:

```
declare
    c_name varchar2(255 char);
begin

    select c.constraint_name into c_name
    from all_constraints c
    join all_cons_columns cc 
        on  cc.table_name = c.table_name 
        and cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
    where 
        cc.table_name = 'MYPROJECT_COST' 
        and cc.column_name ='COST'
        and c.constraint_type = 'C' ;

    if c_name is not null then
        execute immediate 
            'alter table myproject_cost drop constraint "' || c_name || '"';
    end if;
end;
/
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ef40d8be044c1faeb43e257e5cc628a)**:

```
create table myproject_cost (
        id int not null unique,
        detail varchar2(25) not null,
        cost int check(cost >= 500)
    );

insert into MyProject_COST(id, detail, cost) values(1, 'foo', 0);
-- ORA-02290: check constraint (FIDDLE_XUVVCZVSYWWROHKPBFUF.SYS_C0030623) violated

declare
    c_name varchar2(255 char);
begin

    select c.constraint_name into c_name
    from all_constraints c
    join all_cons_columns cc 
        on  cc.table_name = c.table_name 
        and cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
    where 
        cc.table_name = 'MYPROJECT_COST' 
        and cc.column_name ='COST'
        and c.constraint_type = 'C' ;

    if c_name is not null then
        execute immediate 
            'alter table myproject_cost drop constraint "' || c_name || '"';
    end if;
end;
/
-- 1 rows affected

insert into MyProject_COST(id, detail, cost) values(1, 'foo', 0);
-- 1 rows affected
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.But its very tricky for me as I am novice. I have just updated my answer. Can u please show me the simplest way. Thanks

Comment: @kodder360: just `alter table myproject drop constraint cost_project`.